# @PostContruct method does not work with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

Hi I am trying to initialize a field with `@PostConstruct` method but in tests, this method does not fill the `bidiMap` field.

Is there any way to mock `bidiMap` field which is a field of `DataSource` ?

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataSource {

    public DualHashBidiMap<String, String> bidiMap = new DualHashBidiMap();

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadData() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("src/main/resources/static/data.json"), Map.class);
        data.entrySet().stream().forEach(item -> this.bidiMap.put(item.getKey(), item.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
    void shouldReturnPrettifiedUrl_WithQueryParams() throws IOException {
        // Given
        List<String> inputParameters = Arrays.asList("/products?gender=female&tag=123&tag=1234");
        HashMap<String, String> expectedResult = PrettyUrlResponseBuilder.PrettyUrlResponseBuilder().createPrettyUrlResponseWithParams();
        HashMap<String, String> databaseResponse = DatabaseResponse.DatabaseResponse().createDatabaseResponse();
        System.out.println(dataSource);
        // When
        Map<String, String> actualResult = prettyUrlService.toPretty(inputParameters);

        // Then
        assertEquals(expectedResult, actualResult);
    }
```

The class being tested:

```
@Service
public class PrettyUrlService {
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public PrettyUrlService(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public Map<String, String> toPretty(List<String> urlList) throws IOException {
        var data = dataSource.getBidiMap(); // Here, data is null.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're unit testing the `PrettyUrlService` class then you should not need to also test the underlying `DataSource` class within the same test. Simply mocking the `DataSource` interactions and verifying that all the expected interactions are happening should be more than enough.

*E.g. (assuming JUnit 5):*

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class PrettyUrlServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private DataSource dataSource;
  private PrettyUrlService prettyUrlService;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    prettyUrlService = new PrettyUrlService(dataSource);
  }

  @Test
  void exampleTest() {
    DualHashBidiMap<String, String> bidiMap = new DualHashBidiMap();
    // add test data to the map
    bidiMap.put("testKey", "testValue"); // replace with data you need for test
    Mockito.when(dataSource.getBidiMap()).thenReturn(bidiMap);
    
    // insert test logic here (prettyServiceUrl call + assertions)
    // ...

    // finally, verify that dataSource.getBidiMap() was called exactly once
    Mockito.verify(dataSource).getBidiMap();
  }

}
```